# jodatime millis to date issue

Tags: android, jodatime

I think I am missing something really simple but shouldn't this

```
long test = 1401894000; // GMT: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 15:00:00 GMT
DateTime dt = new DateTime(test);
Timber.d("TEST : %s", dt.toString("DD YYYY HH:mm"));
```

output

```
TEST : 04 2014 15:00
```

where what I see is

```
TEST : 17 1970 05:24
```

Im on Android

DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);

compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1401894000` is *[milliseconds](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29)* since Jan 1, 1970.

Which, if we work out is:

- 1401894000 / 1000 = 1401894 seconds
- 1401894 / 60 = 23364.9 minutes
- 23364.9 / 60 = 389.415 hours
- 389.415 / 24 = 16.23 days

Which is between 5am and 6am on Jan 17 - which is the output you're seeing.

Comment: <facepalm> I need a cup of coffee